# Display data in table page logic stuck

Tags: php, mysql

I'm very stuck with my case. Here is I will give that stuck :

I have an table :

```
form_no | model_name | status | date_check
```

Now I have an data :

```
1 | mouse | OK | 26-Apr-2013
2 | mouse | NG | 27-Apr-2013
```

Now I want to show it in my page using PHP code. We see that model_name have a same name, but have different status and date_check.

What I want to do is, how to make it to be 1 information without looping data. So the data will show in my page like this :

```
No | Model Name | Status Yesterday | Status Today
1  | mouse      | OK               | NG
```

-

```
<table>
 <td>No</td><td>Model Name</td><td>Status Yesterday</td><td>Status Today</td>
 <tr>
 <?php
 $query = "SELECT * FROM t_prod";
 $result = mysql_query($query);

 while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $model_name = $data['model_name'];
 ?>

<td>1</td><td><?php echo $model_name; ?></td><td>Status yesterday</td><td>Status Today</td>

 <?php
 }
 ?>
</table>
```

We see that in column Status yesterday and Status Today still not have a PHP code, cause I confused how to make it show based on yesterday and today.

Last time I just make it like this :

I add

```
 $status_yesterday = $data['status'];
 $status_today = ?
```

But it will just for yesterday, and if I add status_today like status yesterday it will be same data.

Comment: Hi! Please see my questions.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `LEFT JOIN` in your query, and create a new column - `status_yesterday`

```
SELECT 
   t.form_no, t.model_name, t.status as status_today, y.status_yesterday
FROM 
   t_prod t
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT model_name, status AS status_yesterday FROM t_prod WHERE date_check = '2013-04-26') y
ON t.model_name = y.model_name
WHERE date_check = '2013-04-27'
GROUP BY model_name
```

see a SQLFiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2de8/3

Note I have hardcoded the dates in the query, but you can modify it using `NOW()` and `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`